# Erro variable stmt of type Statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

To tentando executar a tabela, porem no netbeans ele fica alertando o erro na linha do ExecuteQuery.

> Symbol: method executeQuery(String) location: variable stmt of type Statement

O erro esta grifado, o netbeans alerta que a mensagem acima na parte do executeQuery.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o codigo.

**Classe Conexao**

```
package Model;

import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Conexao {
    public Connection con;
    public Statement stmt;
    public ResultSet rs;

    //Connect Mysql Endereço
    String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    String driver = "";
    String user = "";
    String password = "";

    //Metodos
    public void Connectar(){
        try{
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

        stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

        }catch(Exception e){


        }

    }

    //TESTANDO OUTRO TIPO DE CHAMADA BANCO DE DADOS

    /*public static Connection creatConnection() throws SQLException{
        String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/id6275581_unit";
        String user = "id6275581_unitusername";
        String password = "123456";
        Connection conexaos = null;
        conexaos = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

        return conexaos;
    }*/



}
```

**Classe Login**

```
package View;

import Model.Conexao;
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }


    public void acessar(){
        try{
        Conexao connect = new Conexao();
        connect.Connectar();
        connect.stmt = (Statement) connect.con.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM login";

//ResultSet rsTeste = connect.stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      // PreparedStatement ps = connect.con.prepareStatement(sql);

connect.rs = connect.stmt.executeQuery(sql);
//ResultSet rss = ps.executeQuery();

//ps.execute();

        connect.rs.first();
                if((txtUsuario.getText().equals(connect.rs.getString("username"))) && (txtSenha.getText().equals(connect.rs.getString("password")))){

        }else{
            //AJAX FUTURO
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Senha ou Login Incorreto");
        }



        }catch(SQLException e){

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        label1 = new java.awt.Label();
        label2 = new java.awt.Label();
        label3 = new java.awt.Label();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtUsuario = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();
        txtSenha = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Sisterma Login");
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 102));
        setResizable(false);

        label1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 20)); // NOI18N
        label1.setText("Sistema Academico - Login");

        label2.setText("Usúario:");

        label3.setText("Senha:");

        jButton1.setText("Logar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Cadastre");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtUsuario.setName("txtUsuario"); // NOI18N
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txtUsuario);

        txtSenha.setName("txtSenha"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(txtSenha)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 141, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 93, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(label2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(label3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(txtSenha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 128, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        this.acessar();

    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Cadastro cadastro = new Cadastro();
        cadastro.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private java.awt.Label label1;
    private java.awt.Label label2;
    private java.awt.Label label3;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtSenha;
    private javax.swing.JEditorPane txtUsuario;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Vitor, que erro? Como vamos adivinhar do que se trata? Você precisa mostrar o erro para nós, pois seu código não é executável.

Comment: rapaz eu vou tirar o print , o netbens esta me informando oerro, enfim veja ai o print.

Comment: Nada de erro ainda. Seu print pouco ajudou. Passe o mouse em cima do grifo vermelho q o netbeans mostra o erro numa caixa amarela.

Comment: ja passei, porem ele informa que apenas é um erro,

Symbol: method executeQuery(String)
location: variable stmt of type Statement

Comment: nao dar opção do amarelo

Comment: Cara, só com pedacinhos de codigo e sem poder executar fica dificil ajudar ne. Edite a pegunta e coloque as duas classes envolvidas completas.

Comment: Editei o codigo completo.

Comment: Impossivel saber o erro sem voce não tivesse apresentado os codigos completo mesmo. Veja a resposta com a solução abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando um tipo errado ao que provavelmente espera. O tipo `Statement` que está usando é do pacote `java.beans`, como pode ser visto no import das duas classes da pergunta, quando o esperado é do pacote `java.sql`. Corrija o import das classes para `import java.sql.Statement` que o problema será resolvido.

Comment: o erro persiste do executeQuery, persiste ainda

Comment: @Vitor você corrigiu o import nas duas classes?

Comment: opa, tinha esquecido da primeira classe, muito obrigado, obrigado pela paciência.